# Start My service with other app

Tags: android

I am not sure if there are similar question like this asked before, but I can't find any.

I am planning to start my service every time others click on specific app icon(eg. game).

This is of course with the user permission or settings.
So how do I do that?

My thinking are

1. To recreate a new launcher/icon to bind my service with the other app.
2. To auto start the following code when user click the launcher with some broadcast receiver

> Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
>
> startService(mIntent);

Can anyone show me an example code perhaps a link?
Or guide me on how to do that/have better method on achieving this.

Comment: https://adilatwork.blogspot.in/2015/12/android-start-service-of-another-app.html hope this may help you

Comment: @Basiljose Yes, it did help. However I want to work on the other way round
The tutorial is from export service in app A, then start service with app B. Where B is our code.
What I want is export service in app A(My code), then on open app B, service is launched. I cannot edit anything from app B. Perhaps to do some attachment to the app B(recreate launcher icon?)

Comment: We can see the apps being started in logcat by filtering on the ActivityManager. Maybe you could get some events out of it. However, I'm almost sure that this kind of functionality would be blocked by design in Android, as it would seem to me like a major security flaw...

Comment: @JMLord I feel that too, that is why I am suggesting the 2 method above. These are the method I think probably workable. I am still open to new suggestion.

Comment: What is the purpose of this service? Figuring out the use case might help to find other ways to achieve it...

Comment: @JMLord to simplify usage
Let's say when they are reading a book, a service auto started to read the word to them. they don't need to open my app and start the service themselves.

Comment: I believe you can't do this with a regular service. You'll need an accessibility service to do this. Talkback, for example, reads everything the user focuses.

Comment: How about using the broadcasting receiver, on click and start service?